# using java.util.Scanner to read a file byte by byte

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read a one line file character by character using java.util.Scanner. However I'm getting this exception":

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "contents of my file"
    at java.util.Scanner.nextByte(Scanner.java:1861)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextByte(Scanner.java:1814)
    at p008.main(p008.java:18) <-- line where I do scanner.nextByte()
```

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File source = new File("file.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(source);
    while(scanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println((char)scanner.nextByte());
    }
    scanner.close()
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

Edit: I realized I wrote hasNext() instead of hasNextByte(). However if I do that it doesn't print out anything.

Comment: a Scanner is for parsing character input. I suspect you need an InputStream.

Answer (score 11):

Why on earth would you want to use a scanner to read a file byte by byte? That's like using a wheelbarrow to transport your pocket change. (If you really need a wheelbarrow for your pocket change, let me know so I can become your friend).

But seriously: Class `InputStream` reads bytes from a file, simply and reliably, and does nothing else.

Class `scanner` was recently introduced into the Java API so textbook examples could pull data out of a file with less pain than is usually involved with using the cascade of `new BufferedReader(new InputStream)`. Its specialty is inputting numbers and strings from free-form input files. The `nextByte()` method actually reads one or a few decimal digits from the input stream (if they're there) and converts the number thus scanned into a single byte value.

And if you're reading bytes, why do you want to output them as `char`s? Bytes are *not* chars, and brute-force interconverting will fail in some places. If you want to see the values of those bytes, print them out as they are and you'll see small integers between 0 and 255.

If you want to read `char`s from a file, `FileReader` is the class for you.

Comment: I have a text file starting with the word "Abstract" ( what a suprise.. ). Anyway when I try reading with: Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file); byte b = scanner.nextByte(); I am getting java.util.InputMismatchException. Why am I not seeing any values between 0 and 255, can you please help? The file is UTF-8.

Comment: My answer explained this, but perhaps not very well. Scanner reads and interprets text-form input, not low-level bytes! Try creating a file whose first line reads `1 10 100 1000 hello` and reading that with `Scanner.nextByte()`. You will successfully read and return as bytes the numbers 1, 10 and 100 but suffer an exception on 1000 and (if you read past that) on "hello" because those aren't values that can be represented in a byte.

Answer (score 4):

Scanner is for *parsing* text data - its `nextByte()` method expects the input to consist of digits (possibly preceded by a sign).

You probably want to use a [`FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) if you're actually reading text data, or a [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) if it's binary data. Or a `FileInputStream` wrapped in an [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) if you're reading text with a specific character encoding (unfortunately, `FileReader` does not allow you to specify the encoding but uses the platform default encoding implicitly, which is often not good).

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean "parsing text data" and "reading text data" ?

Comment: @KorayTugay: reading means just taking whatever comes, one byte (or character) after another. Parsing means that you expect the data to have a specific structure or format, such as a string consisting of digits preceded by an optional minus sign, so that you can interpret it as a number.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So nextByte method in Scanner class is for "reading digits" only?

Comment: Sorry to necro but your `FileReader` link directs to `FilterReader`, not `FileReader` :)

Answer (score 2):

When troubleshooting `Scanner`, check for [underlying I/O errors](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#ioException()):

```
if(scanner.ioException() != null) {
  throw scanner.ioException();
}
```

Though I'm with the others - this probably isn't the right class for the job. If you want byte input, use an `InputStream` (in this case, [`FileInputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read())). If you want char input, use a `Reader` (e.g. [`InputStreamReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html)).

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner` is all about reading delimited text (see [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)).

`nextByte` will keep reading until it gets to whichever delimiter you specified (whitespace by default) and then try to convert that string into a byte.

So if you have `123 456` in a file, one call to `nextByte` will return `123`, not `49` (the decimal value for the `1` character).

---

If you want to read byte-by-byte, you could use [`FileInputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html).