# How can I read text from a file in Java with streams of size I choose?

Tags: java, java-io

So I can read a text file with `Java` like this just fine:

```
File file = new File("C:/text.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file,"utf-8");
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    scanner.nextLine();
    // rest of the code...
```

I am not 100% sure but I believe this loads the whole file and then reads the text line by line.

Suppose you have a very large text file where one line might be way too long.

How can I read the text from the file, say like 50 characters per time? What I want is in every iteration I should get 50 characters, not more.

Comment: You would use a BufferedReader in that case and specify the bytes to be read in each iteration.

Comment: @W.K.S Will this avoid loading the whole file in the memory as well?

Comment: Please look this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039229/using-java-util-scanner-to-read-a-file-byte-by-byte

Comment: I believe neither BufferedReader nor Scanner load the entire file into memory.

Comment: You are mistaken. It reads the file line by line and throws each line away. It does not load the entire file into memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and strings
>   using regular expressions.
>
> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern,
>   which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be
>   converted into values of different types using the various next
>   methods.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

here is answer: [Faster way to read file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854859/faster-way-to-read-file)