# Scanner for specified string does not work

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
            String si = "asd";
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(si);
            byte d = sc.nextByte();
```

In the documentation about Scanner(String string) constructor:
Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified string.

This code is crushes with InputMismatchException. What I doing wrong?

Comment: Can we see the stack trace please?

Comment: Why don't you try `byte[] bytes = sc.next().getBytes();`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039229/using-java-util-scanner-to-read-a-file-byte-by-byte

Answer (score 3):

`Scanner.nextByte()` reads the next available byte in the string. `byte` is a numerical value, and as you can see your string only contains characters.

In fact if you try with:

```
String si = "-20 asd";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(si);
byte d = sc.nextByte();
```

It will work, because `-20` is an acceptable `byte`, and after the last line `d` will hold `-20`.

If you want to get the byte representation of your string, just do

```
byte[] bytes = sc.next().getBytes();
```

or even

```
byte[] bytes = si.getBytes();
```

Answer (score 2):

First, is important to know that the range of a `byte` in Java is `[-128, 127]`.

Now, according to Java Docs, the [`nextByte()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextByte%28%29) (emphasis mine):

> **Throws: InputMismatchException** - if the next token does not match the *Integer* regular expression, or is out of range

So, it expects to read a number in the range `[-128, 127]` from the `String`. Otherwise, it will throw that exception.

An example of how can you use it would be:

```
String si = "-128";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(si);
byte d = sc.nextByte();
System.out.println(d); // -128
```

**Edit:** One simple solution to access to the characters of an `String` would be to convert it into an array `char[]`:

```
char[] chars = si.toCharArray();
System.out.println(chars[index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [JavaDoc for nextByte method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextByte%28int%29).
You are trying to read a byte from a string that does not contain any numbers.